# by default how to navigate inside a folder to reach my index,html file

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have started a project in angularJs and I dont want to keep my index.html file in root of my directory. I want to keep it inside a folder called public and when my page loads the index.html needs to be launched by default.[Please refer image below my index.html is inside public folder. when i run my project i am getting below structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VhTO.png)
i have tried when('/', {templateUrl: 'public/index.html'}). in routing but no use

Comment: i think you can configure your routing in your config file

Comment: Are you using any build tool.. gulp/ grunt ? or directly using http-server? You need to do the changes for default landing page and I believe this has nothing to do with router as you want to move the index.html inside some folder instead of keeping it outside.

Comment: If you are using npm http-server then you can use 
-o [path] Open browser window after starting the server. Optionally provide a URL path to open. e.g.: -o /other/dir/ to navigate to your specific folder.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server for reference